# What is this low-growing plant with small yellow fruit found in Roanoke, Virginia? Is it edible?

Tags: identification, weeds, fruits

What is this plant? The little marble sized yellow fruit (tomatoes?) grows on a vine and close to the ground. Is it edible?

I found it near an abandoned nursery in Roanoke, Virginia, where other tomatoes thrive wildly.

[image]

The picture is sourced from my [facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1552920098055348&set=a.192017250812313.56189.100000121198744&type=3&theater).  It's available for public viewing.

Comment: Your link dead ended.  Do you have to have an account to view anything on facebook?  I quit a while ago, could that be why?  Please post pictures right on this site.  Do you know what the plant was like at this nursery?

Comment: I'm  on Facebook and I can't access it either - the link's not working, broken or its not registered as public

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the image; instructions are [here](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/523/how-can-i-add-an-image-to-a-question-answer) on our sister site. Without seeing the plant, there's not much we can do to help you.

Comment: A good description of location (part of the world), plant habit, leave form, trunk, fruits and flower could be enough. But as you see, a picture worths 1000 words.

Comment: Even after your edit I cannot see the image without a facebook account. Please see Niall C.'s link about how to post an image

Comment: I can see the picture,but its hard to say quite what it is, there's so much grass surrounding the stem - I see the stem appears to be thorny, and the fruits are small and yellow, but I don't think they're tomatoes - not enough foliage to be useful for ID either.

Answer (score 3):

This is Carolina Horsenettle, [*Solanum carolinense*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanum_carolinense). It is a noxious weed, spreading by rhizomes and seeds, and it contains a toxic alkaloid (solanine), so is not suitable for consumption. It is poisonous to livestock, as well as resistant to glyphosate (RoundUp) and 2,4D (selective herbicide).

Answer (score 0):

It's likely Solanum elaeagnifolium. Non-edible.

[image]

Comment: Some relatives are edible, even tasty: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physalis But as with all Solanaceae, should be treated with extreme caution until you are certain what they are.